# VB.Net SQL query with parameter/wildcard not returning information

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm a fairly new VB.Net programmer, and I'm working on a program snippet that, when a button is pressed, retrieves information from a SQL database that is a partial match for a string in a text box, and displays it in a DataGridView. However, it only returns information if I enter a complete match, not if I enter a partial one. The query I made works perfectly fine in the Query Builder, but when I use it in my code it has no effect. I have a feeling that this is something to do with some syntax I don't know about, so I would appreciate some help in this matter.

My VB.net code:

```vb
Public Class frmMain
    Private Sub SendQuery(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
        Try
            Me.PartsTableAdapter.PartQuery(Me.SalesDataSet.Parts, tbxQuery.Text)
        Catch ex As System.Exception
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

My SQL query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Parts
WHERE (partno LIKE @PartInput + '%')
```

I'm writing this in Visual Studio 2013, and I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express.

Comment: have you tried trimming your text to make sure there are no spaces?

Comment: Where is the variable @PartInput declared and set Justin?

Comment: @webdad3, just tried that, didn't work.

Comment: MartinJackson, it's not declared or set anywhere, to my knowledge. The Query Editor insisted on changing the query character ? to @Param1, so I changed the name to increase readability.

Comment: Do you have the ability to run the Query Profiler with SQL Express?  If so, look at it to see what the SQL getting sent to the server looks like.

Comment: Steve, I don't believe so. Query Profiler appears to be exclusive to MySQL. The only thing I have similar to that is a SQL Server Profiler, but I don't think that's what you're talking about.

Comment: What parameter is associated with @PartInput? What value should it contain?

Comment: ron tornambe, there is no table column associated with PartInput. It's just the parameter name which the info from the text box is inserted into. Remember - it works fine if I use either the Query Editor or put in a complete match, but with a wildcard it returns nothing to the DataGridView.